# What is Poison Nova?

Tags: diablo-iii

I found the Legendary Item [Andariel's Visage](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/andariels-visage), and one of the properties says:

`40% chance to cast a Poison Nova when you are hit.`

I could observe some green splashing around me when I Leap into a crowd, other than that I can't exactly see a nova effect (like the one in the first Diablo).

How does this work exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That green splash around you when you are hit is what the poison nova effect does.

It does DOT damage based on the DPS of the wearer.

Comment: Wow that's super lame compared to Diablo 2.

Comment: @InvaderSkoodge that's pretty much what everyone thinks as well